# VBA code hanging at row 32767

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that has 137000+ lines in it which means that I do not want to have lots of excel formulas recalculating at every move.  Therefore I created a series of macros to do the job for me.  This was working perfectly until recently, and it now stops at row 32767 and hangs until I crash out.  I don't understand what has changed.  Hopefully one of you clever people can help a novice in need.

Here is an example of one of my subs where this is happening.  All I want to do with this is a vlookup as long as it meets a certain requirement which works fine until I hit the row limit:

```
Sub FGLOH()

Dim FGLOHINT As Integer

FGLOHINT = 3

    Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Select
    Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Range("A" & FGLOHINT).Activate

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Select
    Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Range("A" & FGLOHINT).Activate

If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Range("H" & FGLOHINT).Value = 0

FGLOHINT = FGLOHINT + 1

Else

Dim FGLOH As String
FGLOH = Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Range("A" & FGLOHINT).Value

On Error GoTo 0
On Error Resume Next

Sheets("Calculation of Final LOH").Range("H" & FGLOHINT).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FGLOH, Sheets("Work Centre LOH Lookup").Range("A2:M200000"), 13, False)

FGLOHINT = FGLOHINT + 1

End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Since you got this issue fixed, you might want to take this code to [codereview.se] and get it optimized. With that many rows your `.Select` & `.Activate` is going to significantly slow down your code.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Good shout, thank you.  It does take a long time to run - I have a lot to learn and no one to teach me except you lovely lot!

Comment: `Integer` is essentially useless today. Back in the time of 16-bit computers, 16-bit signed integers were all the rage, but today, rule of thumb, use a `Long` (32-bit) integer type whenever you need an integer value, and keep `Integer` (16-bit) in 1997.

Comment: Thanks - I've just gone through all my code and changed Integer to Long.  Integer shall be filed away never to be used again.

Comment: `Integer` *is* useful when you *must* pass a 16-bit integer type to an API function, for example. But yeah otherwise, a `Long` fits the bill and won't overflow until you try to assign it to 2^31.

Comment: Note that formulas don't "recalculate at every move" unless they are downstream of another formula that changes, or they are volatile, or they are downstream of a volatile formula. See https://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/ for more on this. You can certianly achieve what you are trying to do with formulas in a way that will outperform VBA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

32767 is the maximum value for an `Integer` in VBA. Use a `Long` instead.

```
Dim FGLOHINT As Long
```